# Why is tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath called three times?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know that `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` is used to <s>calculate</s> estimate the cell height. But, when I implement the method, I observe the method it's being called three times. I want to know: why three times?

Answer (score 1):

Estimated height shouldn't be used to calculate anything. It's an *estimated* height and you should be returning a quick number.

Return the calculated, real height in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

The estimated height method will be called by the table view whenever it feels the need to do so. This could be on layout, scrolling, reloading, editing and so on. If you want to know where the call is coming from, set a breakpoint and look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try:
when perform selector like :reloadData,"addToSuperView",setTableFooterView and so on,[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] would be performed.
this selectors about view must refresh the table